# In Swift, how to extract AttributeType from the NSPropertyDescription

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, tableview

I have an array that contains all of the NSPropertyDescriptions for my entity.  Is there a way to extract and store either the attributeType or the attributeValueClassName from that?

The big picture of what I'm trying to do is identify which property names are date type properties.  I have the property names and values each stored separately in a separate arrays and those are used to populate a tableview.  upon clicking any row of the tableview, I need to be able to test to see if the associated property within that particular cell is a date type so that I can use a date picker.

```
 func generateTypeList(_ animal:Animal) -> [String:NSPropertyDescription] {
    
     let dictAttributes4 = animal.entity.propertiesByName
 
     print (dictAttributes4)
     return dictAttributes4
 }
```

Output (this only reflects one property but the array does contain about 20 different properties in total)

```
 <NSAttributeDescription: 0x600002ca8380>), name a_type, isOptional 1,   isTransient 0, entity      Animal, renamingIdentifier a_type, validation predicates (
 ), warnings (
 ), versionHashModifier (null)
 userInfo {
 }, attributeType 700 , attributeValueClassName NSString, defaultValue    (null), preservesValueInHistoryOnDeletion NO
```

Comment: You won't get type from `NSPropertyDescription`, instead try this way

let check = animal.entity.attributesByName
print(check?.values.map { $0.attributeType })

or something like this

check?.values.forEach {
            switch $0.attributeType {
            //your logic goes here
            }
        }

Comment: Thank you!  I tried that and my output from the print is an array filled with a bunch of this "__C.NSAttributeType".  I tried using the switch/case and what I would want to do is a "case NSDate:" but I don't think that's working because the check.values.map isn't populating with the actual attributeTypes for some reason

Comment: I made some progress!  I replaced the attributeType with this and that gave me some output that maybe I can work with: print(check.values.map { $0.attributeValueClassName })

Comment: glad I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

This is what I ended up doing.  I feel like it's not a very sophisticated way, but I got it to work.  I understand the logic of the "let sortedYourArray..." but I don't understand the syntax of why/how it works.  Where can I learn about those parameters  of $0.0 < $1.0 ?  those make no sense to me.

```
    let animalAttributes = animal!.entity.attributesByName

    let sortedYourArray = animalAttributes.sorted( by: { $0.0 < $1.0 })
    
    for attribute1 in sortedYourArray {

        let attributeType2 = attribute1.value.attributeValueClassName
        propertyTypes.append (attributeType2!)

    }
```